# Replace single node in c# tree

Tags: c#, .net, tree, tree-traversal

I have a tree construct in my application which contains hierarchical data of users.

```
public class User {
     //a lot of properties here like Id, Name, Last Name, etc.
     public IEnumerable<User> Employees {get;set;}
}
```

Now I need to replace certain record in this tree with new item.

```
var changedUsers = GetChangedUsers();
// Replace all changed user fields in original hierarchy 
// (only FirstName, LastName, etc. without touching Employees field)
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I have tried to loop with recursion, but stuck with updating record.

```
private void ReplaceUserInHierarchy(User modifiedUser, List<User> users)
        {
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                if (user.Id == modifiedUser.Id)
                {
                    //we should update here somehow
                    return;
                }

                ReplaceUserInHierarchy(modifiedUser, user.Employees);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What degree of elegance is required? Is flattening hierarchy and editing each matched user elegant enough?

Comment: Was that a sarcasm?

Comment: @Gab flatten hierarchy and join to `changedUsers`

Comment: @Gab exactly. Your question missing the main part - code which shows your attempt to solve this task and description of problem (error or incorrect results) which you can't solve

Comment: @tchelidze - How can we do that?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, I tried to loop via recursion, but than stuck in the point when I understood that even when I find the record there is no way to edit that in the original list.

Comment: @Gab good that you have tried to solve it, please add code to your question and we'll explain where the problem is, how to fix it, and probably suggest better solution (if any)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovsky, I have edited my question.

Comment: Why don't you get a new tree from the (changed) backing store? So much more reliable. This looks so much like micro optimizing.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Because it now takes about 30-40 seconds to load whole tree, so I'm trying to optimize it and just update changed nodes.

Comment: 30+ seconds is a good reason. But I do wonder why you would wan to load them all at once. Not just for a UI I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply update user wich matched given id:

```
private void ReplaceUserInHierarchy(User modifiedUser, List<User> users)
{
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        if (user.Id == modifiedUser.Id)
        {
            // update properties of user here
            user.FirstName = modifiedUser.FirstName;
            // etc
            return; // if user can be duplicated in hierarchy, then use continue here
        }

        // assume user cannot be in own employees hierarchy
        ReplaceUserInHierarchy(modifiedUser, user.Employees);
    }
}
```

---

Improving elegance - you can use extension method which flattens hierarchy. Then search for the user you should update will look like:

```
var user = users.Flatten(u => u.Employees).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == modifiedUser.Id);
if (user != null) // you can throw if user not found
    user.FirstName = modifiedUser.FirstName; // etc
```

Flattening can be done as

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(
   this IEnumerable<T> source,
   Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
{
   // null-check arguments
   foreach(var item in source)
   {
       yield return item;
       foreach(var child in Flatten(selector(item), selector))
           yield return child;
   }   
}
```

Further improvements - you can save flattened hierarchy to the dictionary and use it to update several users:

```
var usersById = users.Flatten(u => u.Employees).ToDictionary(u => u.Id);
foreach(var modifiedUser in modifiedUsers)
{
    User user;
    if (!usersById.TryGetValue(modifiedUser.Id, out user);)
       continue; // or throw

    user.FirstName = modifiedUser.FirstName; // etc  
}
```

Further improvements - you can use some library like AutoMapper to do the mapping automatically.

Comment: Is there a way I can say to replace all properties except Employees? (there are about 30 properties)

Comment: Note the last __s__ in `GetChangedUsers();`, your code only caters for one.

Comment: @Gab - sounds like you need to look at AutoMapper or similar.

Comment: @HenkHolterman my code changes all reference**s** of user which have id of `modifiedUser`

Comment: Still I think I need to use "return" instead of "continue" - There can be only single user with specified Id in hierarchy.

Comment: @Gab no duplications? I.e. every user can be in `Employee` list of only one other user?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovsky - Exactly

Comment: Flattening looks more elegant. I will modify your solution for my needs. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovsky - Thanks